# Laravel routes not working inside a prefix unless given a variable

Tags: php, laravel

I'm fairly new to Laravel. I'm having a problem with routing.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'api/v1'],function(){
  Route::resource('results','RequestController');
  Route::get('results/getByName/{name}','RequestController@getByName');
  Route::get('results/getLastTen','RequestController@getLastTen');
});
```

The problem is that the last route under prefix api/v1 does not work. When I call it it shows nothing, not even any error.

The code at the requestController is:

```
public function getLastTen(){
        $results=DB::table('latest_random_trends')->limit(10)->get();
        return $results;
    }
```

Everything is alright with the code on the controller since it works when I call it from the routes.php file outside of the prefix 'api/v1' like this:

```
    Route::get('results/getLastTen','RequestController@getLastTen');
```

but when it is inside the prefix it does not work unless I add a variable to it like this:

```
    Route::get('results/getLastTen/{var}','RequestController@getLastTen');
```

Comment: Are you going to the url `/api/v1/results/getLastTen`?

Comment: Yes, there is nothing wrong with the url. It does not display anything when I call it. However, when I put the route under another prefix like api/v2 it works fine

Comment: What happens if you remove the resource routes? Does it work? If so, I think you might have a conflict between the resource routes and your custom ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a `Route::resource` above it, I think what's happening is that the `show` method on Resource Controller is getting the route instead of the one you wrote.

Try one the following:

- Exclude the show method if you're not going to use it

  ```
  Route::resource('results','RequestController', ['except' => 'show']);
  ```
- Move your custom route above the resource route

  ```
  Route::group(['prefix'=>'api/v1'],function(){
      Route::get('results/getLastTen','RequestController@getLastTen');
      Route::resource('results','RequestController');       
      Route::get('results/getByName/{name}', 'RequestController@getByName');

  });
  ```

For more information, check out the `show` action on [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: I was thinking the same but the last defined routes doesn't override previous routes in case of conflict?

Comment: @Camilo No, the first route to match, the first it will be executed

Comment: The reason because works when adding `{var}` to the end of the route is the same reason of `getByName/{var}` currently works under the resource route. It's because the pattern no longer matches the default `show` action on resource controllers.

Comment: Excuse me for my inexperience, but why would it go to the show method when I specify it that it goes at the getLastTen method?

Comment: Because the `show` method in resource controller determines the url as `results/{something}`. That something var, in this case, is `getLastTen`. It's a regular expression and the `show` method matches that. Since the resource routes were defined before the `getLastTen`, `show` route was triggered and searched a result for the id `getLastTen`. I guess you had the `show` method empty and that's why it didn't show anything before moving the route up